# Injecting key events from android service

Tags: android, android-service

I'm making a custom navigation bar for android. I want to inject KEYCODE_BACK event from any part of application whether I'm on menu, home screen or any application. Basically, any part of android. How can I do that using services. I found one piece of code but it doesn't work coz I have to install application as system.

```
new Thread() {      // requires to use INJECT_EVENTS permission in android
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();           
                inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception when sendKeyDownUpSync", e.toString());
            }
        }

    }.start();
```

For this to work, I use **uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"** but it throws error saying **INJECTING INTO ANOTHER APPLICATION REQUIRES INJECT_EVENT PERMISSION.**

Is there anyway to implement back button through service.

Thanks

Comment: Inject_events is only granted to system apps